# Could not load the default credentials even after setting env

Tags: node.js, express, environment-variables, google-vision

I set up env varible  VISION_KEYFILE_JSON with key values of the vision app, when I console

```
console.log(`key: ${process.env.VISION_KEYFILE_JSON}`);
```

It gives the key, when executing the code

```
const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient({ projectId: config.google.project_id});
```

I got the following error

> Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to
>   https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials
>   for more information.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to also set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` for Application Default Credentials to work. I think setting it to the same value as `VISION_KEYFILE_JSON` is correct.

Comment: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS need to be path name to the key file , Instead of that I have also given  GOOGLE_CLOUD_KEYFILE_JSON, still the issue exists

Comment: did you ever figure this out? same issue rn

Comment: Same issue as well.